# How to plot stack series line graph in R?

Tags: r, plot, linegraph

I would like to plot stack series line graph in same plot. I have been reading around at this forum and tried several mentioned examples. But, I have no luck to get it right.

This is a summary of my data in R:

```
> head(allPAL.DE)
               time02H       time06H       time24H
TT000526   -0.01106224     1.0080723     0.8315261
TT000561   -0.30812201    -0.4085618     0.5446794
TT000794    1.22833349     3.3781206     2.5952071
TT000197   -0.23966166    -0.2603373     0.5623011
TT000238   -0.33446383     0.6522561     0.5815776
TT000684    0.73437943     1.3070386    -1.2774730
```

It is a data frame R object:

```
> str(allPAL.DE)
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ time02H: num  -0.0111 -0.3081 1.2283 -0.2397 -0.3345 ...
 $ time06H: num  1.008 -0.409 3.378 -0.26 0.652 ...
 $ time24H: num  0.832 0.545 2.595 0.562 0.582 ...
```

I wish to produce a stack series line graph like below with R:

[image: stack series line graph]

Could the community kindly share with me the way to produce aforementioned graph in R?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Do you really want to make a plot of stacked values, when your data contain negative numbers? This is hard to interpret visually, and could easily be misleading.

Comment: @DrewSteen It is not a must. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that will give you what you want.

```
#Example Data
n = 6
time02H = abs(rnorm(n))
time06H = abs(rnorm(n))
time24H = abs(rnorm(n))

allPAL.DE = data.frame(time02H,time06H,time24H)

plot(0,0,xlab="Time",ylab="Values",type="n",xlim=c(0,2),ylim=c(min(allPAL.DE,0),max(allPAL.DE)),axes="FALSE")
box()
axis(1,0:2,c("time02H","time06H","time24H"))
axis(2)
abline(h=0,col="grey",lty=2,lwd=2)

for(i in 1:nrow(allPAL.DE)){
    lines(0:2,allPAL.DE[i,],col=i,lwd=2)
}
```

You could add different options, colors and text to make the plot look nicer but its the basic idea that you were asking for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your R demonstration. It is indeed helpful.